# I get words with commas between letters instead of between words

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, join

I get a strings with | between letters instead of between the words
for example w|o|r|d,|o|k
instead of word|ok

It is also not possible to do join on list of lists but a list of strings

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')


intersect1=""

for j in range(len(data)):
      x=str(data.iloc[j, 1])
      #print(x)
      x=x.split("|")
      x = x[:-1]
      y=str(data.iloc[j, 2])
      y=y.split("|")
      y = y[:-1]
      intersect= list(set(x) & set(y)) 
      #intersect1.append(intersect)
      intersect1+=str(intersect)
      print(intersect1)
      print ("|".join(intersect1))
      #print(intersect1)
      #intersect1.join("|")
      #print(intersect1)
#print(intersect1)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(list(intersect1))
df3.to_csv('intersect1.csv')
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: please provide an example: before and after + desired output. + elaborate more on the probem.

Comment: intersect1 is not a list but a string. try getting intersect1 to be a list first